# Multiple maven project with different package

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-2

I have one maven project who generates a .war. Now I want to create a new project, and I want to use some classes from this project to create a .jar.

What is the best way to do it?
Can I create different packages using modules or package is just configured in parent? Or Should I create a different maven project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you convert the first project to a multi-module maven project, one being a jar and the other being the war.

Comment: Thanks vikingsteve, Is there any automatic way to do it using intellij?

Comment: Not automatically. I would start by splitting into a multi module maven project by defining the root pom and the child poms, and go from there.